# pl sql, make select only if

Tags: sql, select, if-statement

Hello I'm new to pl sql and am trying to make a query like this:

```
SELECT column1, sum (column2)
FROM table1
WHERE sum (column2) <> 0
GROUP BY column1
```

Basically what I would like to do is to select only those rows where the sum(column2) grouped by column1 is <> 0.

This query gives me an ORA-00934 error which makes sense because in the WHERE clause it is not specified that the sum operation must be grouped by column1 (or at least I think this is the problem).

I tried different solutions like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(column2) <> 0 then (SUM(column2), column1) END 
...
```

but pl-sql does not like it.

What works would be:

```
SELECT column1, case when SUM(column2) <> 0 then SUM(column2) END
...
```

But in this case I don't have exactly what I want since the result is a pseudotable like the one from 
SELECT column1, SUM(column2)... 
except for the fact that I see white fields where the SUM(column2) = 0 while I don't want to see the whole row.

Can anybody help me?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your `WHERE` clause into `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT column1, sum (column2)
FROM table1
GROUP BY column1
HAVING sum (column2) <> 0
```

The `HAVING` clause gets evaluated after `GROUP BY` has been applied.

Comment: Right! It was easy! as I said, I'm new to sql... thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT column1, sum (column2)
FROM table1
GROUP BY column1
HAVING sum (column2) <> 0
```

> The Oracle PL/SQL HAVING clause is used to filter or restrict the groups formed by the GROUP_BY clause.

[Source](http://psoug.org/definition/HAVING.htm)

Comment: that easy?! thank you a lot! as I said I'm new to sql and didn't know about the having clause.